# Backbone.js Calculator App Architechture (Singleton Model)

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm looking for some guidance on Architecture for an app I'm building in Backbone.

It's basically a multi-page App that calculates data based on an initial data-set. The Initial data-set is country specific and is getting pulled in from a JSON file.

When the app fires up, the data-set is used as the defaults: in my main Backbone.Model. These defaults then have to be processed/calculated and set as additional model attributes. These attribute represent my app state. Some can be overridden from the UI. So to recap, I'm using a singleton Backbone.Model to store the initial data, I'm then building the rest of the data up on the Models initialize method.

I then recalculate the data-set attributes on model.change event. This fires the models custom method updateAttributes() which recalculates data. It seems to me like it's pretty inefficient because I'm calculating the attributes, first in the initialize method, and again in the updateAttributes method.

After the values are all processed the data set is complete and can be applied to the app templates. The tricky part now is that some of the calculated data in the set are now editable from the UI. Once these default attributes are edited from the UI I don't want the updateAttributes method to recalculate their values because they are no longer default data, they are now userDefined data.

I'm not quite sure where to go from this point, I'm thinking of setting some attributes on the (rapidly expanding) model such as attributeNameSetFromUI: true, and then having some if() statements in the updateAttributes() method that check for these and skip over that part of the calculation if the default isn't necessary.

I'm not even sure if a large singleton Model is the way to go, it seems to work well enough.

If anyone has some tips for this scenario that would be awesome. I'm new to Backbone, finding it quite challenging!

Comment: when the UI update, the base default data should be cloned for calculation? let's there is a `App._defaultDataset` once you completed all process in your initialization, and then store it in your singleton model. whenever your UI view initialized, clone it and use it for calculation, `var UIData = _.clone(App._defaultDataset)`. so, it won't be changed at all. I dont know if I understand your question.

Comment: No, the data does not need cloning. It just needs recalculating. Lets say I have DataA and DataB in my default dataset; on model initialize, I create DataC, which equals DataA * DataB. There is a fairly long chain of calculations that happen on model init and then again on model update. However, if DataC is then changed from the UI, this new user defined figure should override DataA * Data B.